# %ABAT-W-CREPRCERR in ActiveBatch 11

Tags: automation, batch-processing, fatal-error

Our client uses an automation software called ActiveBatch (by Advanced Systems Concepts, Inc.). They're currently using ActiveBatch v8 and is now on the the process of migrating the automated jobs to a newer ActiveBatch v11.

Most the jobs have no problems coping with the newer software and they're running OK as of this writing. However, there is one job that is unable to run, rather, initialize in the first place. This job runs OK on v8. Whenever this job is being run on v11, it produces an error message:

> %ABAT-W-CREPRCERR, error creating batch process for job %1

Quite self-explanatory; means the process for the particular job was not created. As per checking the user manual, it stated that the job's log file might explain more why the error occurred. Problem is, the log file is not very helpful as it only show *magic numbers* shown below:

> ï»¿

Further readings states that it's Byte Order Mark for UTF-8. I don't know much about this stuff but since the log file only contains those characters, I'm not sure they're helpful at all.

Another thing, if I run the job manually (running EXE via Windows Explorer), no problems will be encountered and it will be a success. The job by the way is a Power Builder 9 application.

Comment: You should realize that your "ActiveBatch" question has _no relation_ with the `batch-file` tag you included in the question. You should read a description of any tag before you use it. I suggest you to remove such a tag...

Comment: I thought I just entered _batch_. Anyway, thank you for that comment.